# C# - getting current selected paper size of a printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printers

I am working with printing the documents programmatically. For this purpose, I need to get the currently selected `PaperSize` of a Printer.

I searched and found this code which gets all paper sizes of all printers,

```
var printDoc = new PrintDocument();

foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(printer);
    Console.WriteLine("**************************");

    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;

    foreach (PaperSize paperSize in printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"PaperName:{paperSize.PaperName}, PaperSize: {paperSize.Height},{paperSize.Width}");
    }
}
```

But, I need currently selected paper size of a printer.

[image]

You can see in above screenshot the currently selected Paper Size is A4. I wants to know, is there any way to get this paper size using any C# code programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.defaultpagesettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-printing-printersettings-defaultpagesettings) which gives you the default page settings for a given printer. Given a certain `PageSettings` object, you can retrieve [the specific papersize](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-printing-pagesettings-papersize).

Comment: Thanks you saved me! Its working `"Paper Size: " + printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.PaperName`